# How making only small hills flatter in landscape?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes, geometry, tools

I have a landscape where I only want to make the small hills and bumps much smaller. However, the basic shape and larger rocks should be preserved. Is there any tool etc. with which you can only make all the smaller bumps flatter to a certain degree? I am grateful for any help :)

[image]

Comment: What is the source of your terrain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Smooth Modifier

**Smooth** modifier could work for you ... for more details see [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/smooth.html).

[image]

[image]

### Weight from Slope

Also what can help is *Vertex Group* based on *Slope*. If you enable *Landscape* add-on (found under *Properties panel (N) > Create > Landscape Tools* > **Weight from Slope** ...

[image]

In *Weight Paint* mode you can contrast weight with *Brush > Overlay* and weight set zero ...

[image]

In modifier select this generated vertex group ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Unfortunately it doesn't help enough unless you make it so strong that all details are lost.

Comment: Factor should work like a threshold to separate a specific kind of deformation. Repeat than should be applied on this specific area ... Could you share sample of terrain and probably would be helpful if you can add example of expected result (even flatten by sculpting manually) just to be sure of final look. In your description you want to eliminate small bumps (that Modifier should handle it) and it is unclear to me what kind of details you need to preserve. Thank you

Comment: Oh i did something wrong here i've noticed now. Together with the vertex group it´s pretty good. Thank you very much! 

Answer (score 4):

I suggest weight painting your low hills. Then go into edit mode, deselect all with Alt+A and then select your new vertex group (created by the weight paint). Now place your 3d cursor at the base of your lanscape and set your transform pivot point to 3d cursor. Now scale the selected areas (your painted group) on the Z axis until you get the desired effect. Additionally, you can go to object mode and add a smooth modifier. Select your group as the vertex group and smooth on the Z axis only. Now play with the repeat and factor until you get the desired effect. If you need screenshots, let me know. If you are familiar with sculpting, you can smooth out your low hills there too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Hmm but then it would be easier to use just the sculpt flat mode and make it with that i think. I was hoping there might be an automation for this. There are thousands of small hills in the landscape, but they are also on top of larger hills.

Comment: @RowDogSA ... sorry I start to read your answer about Scaling in Z and OP's comment its easier to sculpt directly ... so I missed your last part mentioning Smooth modifier as well. BTW scaling whole vertex group on Z sounds like it destroys this kind of model shown in OP's screen because small bumps are not at the same level.

Comment: Whatever works best for you. You will have to do the hard work of smoothing out all the small hills, wherever they are, so taking the time to create a weight group will give you better contol over your landscape.

Answer (score 2):

### Sculpting is probably the quickest way.

Try using the Flatten brush or the Smooth brush to paint away the small hills and bumps.

Tip: Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you're using any brush to access the Smooth brush.

Comment: Yes probably there is no other way.